# Why does pay to pubkey hash contain OP_CHECKSIG at the end instead of beginning?

Tags: script

According to the [bitcoin wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script), the most common form of transaction (pay-to-pubkey-hash) looks like this:

```
scriptPubKey: OP_DUP OP_HASH160 <pubKeyHash> OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG
scriptSig: <sig> <pubKey>
```

I am curious why `OP_CHECKSIG` comes at the end. Couldn't we check the signature even before doing the hash?

More precisely, couldn't it instead do:

```
scriptPubKey: OP_CHECKSIGVERIFY OP_DUP OP_HASH160 <pubKeyHash> OP_EQUAL
scriptSig: <pubKey> <sig>
```

This way you don't have to go through all the hashing if the pubkey and sig don't match to begin with.

I'm sure there's a good reason for this or i'm completely misunderstanding something, please enlighten me. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Couldn't we check the signature even before doing the hash?

We certainly could, but that would be silly. The hash is about 1000x faster than checking a signature. Doing the signature check when the hash fails would be a waste of time

> More precisely, couldn't it instead do:
>
> scriptPubKey: OP_CHECKSIGVERIFY OP_DUP OP_HASH160  OP_EQUAL

No, that certainly wouldn't work. The OP_CHECKSIGVERIFY would remove the public key from the stack, so there is nothing to compare it with. The OP_DUP would always fail, as there is nothing to duplicate anymore.

Comment: aha i see. thanks for the answer. Just to make sure i understood completely, so if we do `scriptPubKey: OP_DUP OP_CHECKSIGVERIFY OP_HASH160 <pubKeyHash> OP_EQUAL` and `scriptSig: <sig> <pubKey>`, this would: 1. work; 2. but not efficient therefore not used because hashing is much faster than checksig?

Comment: Not quite. After OP_DUP, your stack will be <sig> <pubkey> <pubkey>. Invoking OP_CHECKSIGVERIFY at that point will do a verification with <pubkey> as signature.

Comment: What would work (but be inefficient): scriptSig={<pubkey> <sig>}, scriptPubKey={OP_OVER OP_CHECKSIGVERIFY OP_HASH160 <pubkeyhash> OP_EQUAL}.

Comment: Actually, the scriptSig would be "<sig> <pubkey>" to use OP_OVER. If it was already "<pubkey> <sig>" the suggestion in the first comment would work, but it would require a change in the scriptSig, not only the scriptPubKey.